# How can I create and drop the database using Python code?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, python-2.7, mysql-python

I'm very new to Python. How can we drop and create the database in Python?

I'm using MySql and Windows server 2003.

Note: I have all the queries, Drop, create and insert records everything in a `input.sql`

So I want to import input.sql.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the `mysql` client, then this is trivial:

```
mysql -u username -p database < input.sql
```

This will prompt you for a password; if you want to supply the password inline:

```
mysql -u username -ppassword database < input.sql
```

Run any of the above from Python using the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module.

The not-so-easy way would be to read each line of the file - do some logic to grab entire SQL statements - and then execute it against the database "manually", but this would just replicate what the `mysql` command is doing:

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(username="foo",passwd="secret",db="mydb")
c = db.cursor()

with open('input.sql') as f:
   for line in f:
      proper_sql = some_magic_function(line)
      c.execute(proper_sql)
      db.commit()
```

Comment: Plus, the *not-so-easy* way would not work the same, as the default mysql client will detect open brackets etc. and thus allow statements spanning over multiple lines.